# Deep recursion in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a problem with deep recursion in scheme
The output should be

```
(1 2 3 (4 5))
  ~> ((1) (2) (3) ((4) (5)))
```

But my output is `(1 (2 (3 ((4 (5 ())) ()))))`.
It seems like the quote is at the wrong place
I got these

```
(define (DoublebubbleLst lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((not (pair? lst)) 
         (append lst))
        (else(list
              (DoublebubbleLst (car lst))     
              (DoublebubbleLst (cdr lst))))))
```

And what's my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(define (double-bubble-list lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((not (list? (car lst)))
         (cons (list (car lst))
               (double-bubble-list (cdr lst))))
        (else (cons (double-bubble-list (car lst))
                    (double-bubble-list (cdr lst))))))
```

Example:

```
> (double-bubble-list '(1 2 3 (4 5)))
'((1) (2) (3) ((4) (5)))
```